# Why does my function stop working without an alert?

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

So I've got this function right here in my view:

```
function izbrisi() {
        var b = document.getElementById('proizvod').value;
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("IzbrisiProizvod", "Proizvod")',
                data: { id: b }
            }).done(function () {
                alert('Izbrisan');
                });
            alert('Izbrisan');  @* bez ovoga se ne brise proizvod *@
        }
    }
```

The controller it's passed to:

```
public ActionResult izbrisiProizvod(int Id)
        {
            RadniProizvod.IzbrisiProizvod(Id);
            return View();
        }
```

And finally the "IzbrisiProizvod" method:

```
public void IzbrisiProizvod(int IdProizvoda)
        {
            Proizvod izbrisaniProizvod = azilEntities.Proizvods.FirstOrDefault(x => x.idProizvoda == IdProizvoda);
            azilEntities.Proizvods.Remove(izbrisaniProizvod);
            azilEntities.SaveChanges();
        }
```

For whatever reason, if I don't add the final alert (the one where there's a comment), the code just will not work. Nothing gets deleted, nothing gets reported to the console. As soon as I add in the final alert, it will magically start working.

Can someone explain this magic to me?

Comment: Perhaps you should also add `.fail` in case your request fails.

Comment: Is `izbrisiProizvod(int Id)` triggered on debugging ?!

Comment: Without the "alert", neither the controller, nor the method are at all triggered. With the alert, they are.

Answer (score 1):

Always write your jquery functions like this, as per documentation. (The always is optional)

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqXHR object for this request
var jqxhr = $.ajax( "example.php" )
  .done(function() {
    alert( "success" );
  })
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert( "error" );
  })
  .always(function() {
    alert( "complete" );
  });
```

So in your case:

```
function izbrisi() {
        var b = document.getElementById('proizvod').value;
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("IzbrisiProizvod", "Proizvod")',
                data: { id: b }
            }).done(function () {
                alert('Izbrisan');
            }).fail(function() {
                   alert( "error" );
            }).always(function() {
                   alert( "complete" );
           });
        }
    }
```

And maybe change alerts to console log or similar.

Comment: Ok so this is really weird. The code you wrote does not work AS IS. However after I add an alert to its' very last line, it then WORKS. What doesn't make even more sense is that it triggers the FAIL and the ALWAYS, but not the DONE, despite the fact that it then works. Again, without the alert, it still doesn't.

Comment: I changed the code a bit to catch the error. Alert the error to figure out the failure reason. By the way, why are you returning a view in an ajax call?

Comment: I don't actually need the view, just to do stuff with the data, so I changed it to return new empty result just to see if that's it. It didn't change anything. I do notice an error thrown in the console now: NS_ERROR_XPC_SECURITY_MANAGER_VETO:

Answer (score 0):

> For whatever reason, if I don't add the final alert (the one where there's a comment), the code just will not work. Nothing gets deleted, nothing gets reported to the console. As soon as I add in the final alert, it will magically start working.

Your ajax only contains the `.done()` promise callback. This will only execute if the ajax request receives a 200 success code. You can add in the `.fail()` promise to with a unique alert to see what is happening.

In your code, the final alert is fired no matter what.

Try this to help see what is going on. Use this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/m458hvd6/) and open your console also. Note the different alert messages in the `.done()` and `.fail()` promises.

```
  //var b = document.getElementById('proizvod')?.value;
  $.ajax({
    url: '@Url.Action("IzbrisiProizvod", "Proizvod")',
    data: {
      id: 'someData'
    }
  }).done(function() {
    alert('success');
  }).fail(function() {
    alert('error');
  });

  console.log('i fire no matter what');
```

Comment: It doesn't work and the page refreshes way too fast for me to catch anything, but your answer has actually given me an idea and I think I solved it.

Comment: happy it was able to help

Answer (score 0):

Try Network tool within your browser dev tools. For example for [Firefox Dev Tools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Network_Monitor). When you click your element (let's say button) you should see new http request in the list of all request within Network tool. If you don't then your ajax call didn't happen at all or it was happen on previous page because you've experienced page reloading. Check if Proizvod actually deleted. If it is then your js function works but you don't see response. If there is s new http request within Network tool, inspect it a little bit to see what is happen (just click on it and in the right you will see details).

Also, you can open console and instead click the html element type in your console: `izbrisi()`. Function should execute and if it works you will see a new http request in Network tool and your alert for `done` will popup. If this is the case then your html element has default behavior on click event. So you should prevent it in order to prevent page reloading. Let say that you use a button for click on it. The button html should look like:

```
<button onclick="izbrisi(e)">Izbrisi</button>
```

And the js function:

```
function izbrisi(e) {
   e.preventDefault();
   // ... your code goes here
}
```